# jQuery rapid toggling effect (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an offensive script here that causes the nav bar to rapidly toggle in Jquery.  It works fine in Google Chrome, but Firefox doesn't seem to like it.

http://www.morelyorsch.com/

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
$j("ul#nav li").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $j(this).toggleClass("hover");
   $j('ul.children:first',this).closest('ul').show();
  });
$j("ul#nav li").on('mouseleave', function(){
    $j(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $j('ul.children:first',this).closest('ul').hide();
 });
});
```

My suspicion is that the 'this' argument is too broad and causing the event to toggle repeatedly instead of just the each of the first ul's with the children class, but I'm out of ideas on fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

try using addClass and removeClass instead..

example:

```
(function(){
    $("ul#nav li").on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
       $('ul.children:first',this).closest('ul').show();
      });
    $("ul#nav li").on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul.children:first',this).closest('ul').hide();
     });
    })();
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, but that was my first solution.  It's still in the javascript code comments.

Comment: so did it or did not solve the problem ? do I need to look through the problem deeper or it is solved ?

Comment: Did not fix unfortunately.  The problem isn't the toggleClass, it's that the selector is being repeatedly triggered and fired.

Comment: actually I tested the code on firefox and it worked without that stuttering problem .. It would be much better if you can add the html code parts involved to your question so that I can test on fiddle and find you a solution

Comment: The URL if you want to test it is here:

http://www.morelyorsch.com/

A codepen to play with it is here, though I haven't broken it up into separate files yet.

http://codepen.io/NoMan2000/pen/zBnvx

Comment: now I'm pretty sure it is not this part that is causing the flickering because if you disable the hiding function it still disappears and appears where it could not disappear if it was doing that from there !

Comment: what is with the jquery.bxSlider.min.js library ? when I disable it the whole thing doesn't work !

Comment: I think it is the source of your problem